# How to implement websockets in Progress OpenEdge?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to implement a websocket-server with Progress OpenEdge. I still didn't get it working.

I've successfully created a socket-server with the example i-sktsv1.p from [here](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvpin%2Fexamples-using-abl-sockets.html%23).

When I run my html-page, which looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>WebSocket Client</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var wsUri = "ws://localhost:3333/";
  var output;

  function init() {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket() {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    // websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

  function onOpen(evt) {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
  }

  function onClose(evt) {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt) {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt) {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message) {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message) {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
  </script>
<body>
  <h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I getting a error that the websocket connection could not be established.

The problem is (I think) that Progress offers a socket, not a **web**socket. Do you know how to get this working?

Comment: There's support for sockets but no built in support for websockets. You need to implement handshaking etc by yourself.

Maybe it's easier to use a stand alone websocket server and then connect that to your Progress system via an API or similar.

Comment: As @Jensd said, there is no built in support for websockets. We have tried taking a look at implementing before, but found it would be much easier to use another language for a websocket server and have it communicate to OpenEdge.